# Coincidence of $x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ and $\sin x$ in an interval

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Plotting $f(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ and $g(x)=\sin x$, one can see that these two function are coincide in an interval $I\subset(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. On the other hand, Taylor series for $\sin x$ has other terms $\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...$. Does the coincidence of $f(x)$ , $g(x)$ mean that $\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...$ has no effect on value of $\sin x$ for all $x\in I$?? Why?

[image]

Comment: They don't coincide exactly; the approximation gets worse as $x$ tends away from zero.

Comment: Even the "small-angle approximation" $ \ \sin x \ \approx \ x \ $ would show excellent agreement on a graph that small for angles out to $ \ |x| \ = \ 0.3 \ (radians) \ . $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions don't coincide exactly, even though it looks that way. We can estimate the difference for, say, $x = 1/2$: The difference is the alternating series

$$\frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \frac{x^9}{9!} - ...$$

and so it's bounded by the first term; this difference is then at most

$$\frac{1}{5!} \left(\frac 1 2\right)^5 = \frac{1}{120} \cdot \frac 1 {32} \approx \frac{1}{3000}$$

This is pretty minor, and not noticable on the graph. Since $x$ is small, and we're raising it to a high power before dividing it by a very large number, it has fairly little effect; the errors get worse as $x$ grows, however, and are quite obvious at $x = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the good answer given by T. Bongers, just for personal curiosity, change f(x] to (x - x^3 /6 + x^5 / 120) and plot the two functions as you already did. On your plot, you will not be able to distinguish the curves.